# Random number generator independence

Tags: random-variable, independence, random-generation, reproducible-research, generator

I have a naïve question about random number generators.
Say I want to generate a set of random variables from different exponential distributions,$$X_i \sim \mathcal {Exp}(\lambda_i)$$ Assume the$X_i$'s are independent, and $i=1,2,...,1000$.

I want to repeat this process 100 times. In other words, I would like 100 sets of 1000 independent RV's at the end.

The question is : if I set a different seed each time, say $seed = 1,2,...,100$ for the reproducibility, will this affect the independence assumption? My concern is that, otherwise, for every set, the 1000 RV's are generated with the same seed. If there exists some $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$, then for these sets, we will always have $X_i=X_j$. And this breaks up the independence assumption.

If my understanding is correct, do we have to set up 100*1000 seeds instead? Or if there is some other convenient way?

Comment: Why do you think keeping the parameter the same would have anything to do with getting the same values out?

Comment: Changing the seeds for each of the $100$ experiments is not recommended as it may on principle create dependence between the experiments. Starting with a seed like 1 and running $1000$ call to `rexp()` produces a pseudo-random sequence that is iid $\mathcal E$, at least modulo standard statistical tests. Changing the seed for each of the 10⁶ calls to `rexp()` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your reply. I guess I didn't get your first sentence. Could you be more specific why this wil create dependence between the experiments? If it's too complicated, could you list one or two references? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica This is my concern. Same parameter ($\lambda$) and same seed will generate same value. So in my setting, $X_i=X_j$ in every experiment, then they are not independent..

Comment: Yes, if you set the same seed you get the same uniform, that's *by design*. You don't set a seed for every observation you want to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi: Just set the seed to some value initially say 123.( outside any loops,
before any calculations start ). Then you still have reproducibility and the problem that you describe goes away.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you mean just set one seed and generate all100*1000 random values together?

Comment: I think you're the right answer here. Just wanna make sure one thing. If I still use 100 different seeds, and every seed is outside of a for loop, I will still have all the values independent within and between every experiment, right?

Comment: No, the answer suggests using a _single_ seed for all 100 replications (of the 1000 simulations). Otherwise how can you assess "independence" between the seeds?

Comment: Jeffrey: You're better off just using one seed because, as @X'ian mentioned, you sort of introduce a dependence ( I don't know if it's significant. Maybe you could comment on that  ) by using multiple seeds. I didn't even think of that but maybe that's because I don't see the use of using multiple seeds.

Comment: @Xi'an Could you tell us how significant this dependence will be if we set multiple seeds? I totally agree with you and mlofton  that setting one seed is the best answer! However, the price is setting one seed means it's a very long loop, so I would like some acceleration by parallelizing every experiment. How strong the dependence will be if I set one unique seed for each parallel job?